# What is null-free code and how is it applied to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, functional-programming, prototypal-inheritance

I recently stumbled up on a reference of the concept of null-free code - but didn't find a good explanation on how it works or what it really is.

What is null-free code and how is it applied to Javascript?

Comment: what is this "reference", and what did it have to say on the matter?  did it even mention javascript?

Comment: fwiw when i search "null-free code" on google, this 1-hour old question is ranked #1 – so if it's even a thing, i really doubt it has much popularity, at least as described as *null-free code*.

Comment: It was on Quora where a team leader would instruct his team mates to follow null-free code as a best practice.

Comment: Its more of a Java thing, not really JavaScript. https://shekhargulati.com/2015/07/28/day-4-lets-write-null-free-java-code/

Comment: By *null-free*, do you mean [total functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)?

Answer (score 1):

While not specific to Javascript, I think this illustrates the concept suitably: https://clipperhouse.com/principles-of-null-free-programming-4212f02167a3

The core concept is principally that you should avoid imbuing null with meaning, such as using it as a signal. Functions should not be designed “handle” null, nor repeatedly branch code based on the nullity of an object.

The very succinct guidelines he presents:

> - Passing a null is a programming error
> - Branching on null is a programming error